# Анимация шестерёнок в svg

Tags: css, svg

Всех приветствую! Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать прокрутку шестерёнок вокруг себя? Свойство transform-origin: 50% 50%; не помогло. Классы навешены на path

```css
.generate-test__gear--1 {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation: animateClouds 3.5s linear infinite;
}

.generate-test__gear--2 {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation: animateClouds 3.5s linear infinite;
}

.generate-test__gear--3 {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation: animateCloudsBack 3.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animateClouds {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animateCloudsBack {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg
    width="61"
    height="52"
    viewBox="0 0 61 52"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    class='generate-test__gears'
  >
    <path
      class='generate-test__gear--1' d="M19.4298 12.98C19.4698 12.66 19.4998 12.34 19.4998 12C19.4998 11.66 19.4698 11.34 19.4298 11.02L21.5398
      9.37C21.7298 9.22 21.7798 8.95 21.6598 8.73L19.6598 5.27C19.5698 5.11 19.3998 5.02 19.2198 5.02C19.1598
      5.02 19.0998 5.03 19.0498 5.05L16.5598 6.05C16.0398 5.65 15.4798 5.32 14.8698 5.07L14.4898 2.42C14.4598
      2.18 14.2498 2 13.9998 2H9.99984C9.74984 2 9.53984 2.18 9.50984 2.42L9.12984 5.07C8.51984 5.32 7.95984
      5.66 7.43984 6.05L4.94984 5.05C4.88984 5.03 4.82984 5.02 4.76984 5.02C4.59984 5.02 4.42984 5.11 4.33984
      5.27L2.33984 8.73C2.20984 8.95 2.26984 9.22 2.45984 9.37L4.56984 11.02C4.52984 11.34 4.49984 11.67
      4.49984 12C4.49984 12.33 4.52984 12.66 4.56984 12.98L2.45984 14.63C2.26984 14.78 2.21984 15.05 2.33984
      15.27L4.33984 18.73C4.42984 18.89 4.59984 18.98 4.77984 18.98C4.83984 18.98 4.89984 18.97 4.94984
      18.95L7.43984 17.95C7.95984 18.35 8.51984 18.68 9.12984 18.93L9.50984 21.58C9.53984 21.82 9.74984
      22 9.99984 22H13.9998C14.2498 22 14.4598 21.82 14.4898 21.58L14.8698 18.93C15.4798 18.68 16.0398
      18.34 16.5598 17.95L19.0498 18.95C19.1098 18.97 19.1698 18.98 19.2298 18.98C19.3998 18.98 19.5698
      18.89 19.6598 18.73L21.6598 15.27C21.7798 15.05 21.7298 14.78 21.5398 14.63L19.4298 12.98ZM17.4498
      11.27C17.4898 11.58 17.4998 11.79 17.4998 12C17.4998 12.21 17.4798 12.43 17.4498 12.73L17.3098
      13.86L18.1998 14.56L19.2798 15.4L18.5798 16.61L17.3098 16.1L16.2698 15.68L15.3698 16.36C14.9398
      16.68 14.5298 16.92 14.1198 17.09L13.0598 17.52L12.8998 18.65L12.6998 20H11.2998L11.1098 18.65L10.9498
      17.52L9.88984 17.09C9.45984 16.91 9.05984 16.68 8.65984 16.38L7.74984 15.68L6.68984 16.11L5.41984
      16.62L4.71984 15.41L5.79984 14.57L6.68984 13.87L6.54984 12.74C6.51984 12.43 6.49984 12.2 6.49984
      12C6.49984 11.8 6.51984 11.57 6.54984 11.27L6.68984 10.14L5.79984 9.44L4.71984 8.6L5.41984 7.39L6.68984
      7.9L7.72984 8.32L8.62984 7.64C9.05984 7.32 9.46984 7.08 9.87984 6.91L10.9398 6.48L11.0998 5.35L11.2998
      4H12.6898L12.8798 5.35L13.0398 6.48L14.0998 6.91C14.5298 7.09 14.9298 7.32 15.3298 7.62L16.2398
      8.32L17.2998 7.89L18.5698 7.38L19.2698 8.59L18.1998 9.44L17.3098 10.14L17.4498 11.27ZM11.9998 8C9.78984
      8 7.99984 9.79 7.99984 12C7.99984 14.21 9.78984 16 11.9998 16C14.2098 16 15.9998 14.21 15.9998 12C15.9998
      9.79 14.2098 8 11.9998 8ZM11.9998 14C10.8998 14 9.99984 13.1 9.99984 12C9.99984 10.9 10.8998 10 11.9998
      10C13.0998 10 13.9998 10.9 13.9998 12C13.9998 13.1 13.0998 14 11.9998 14Z"
      fill="#ABD18B"
    />
    <path
      class='generate-test__gear--2'
      d="M57.9532 15.6534C57.9799 15.44 57.9999 15.2267 57.9999 15C57.9999 14.7734 57.9799 14.56 57.9532
      14.3467L59.3599 13.2467C59.4866 13.1467 59.5199 12.9667 59.4399 12.82L58.1066 10.5134C58.0466 10.4067
      57.9332 10.3467 57.8132 10.3467C57.7732 10.3467 57.7332 10.3534 57.6999 10.3667L56.0399 11.0334C55.6932
      10.7667 55.3199 10.5467 54.9132 10.38L54.6599 8.61337C54.6399 8.45337 54.4999 8.33337 54.3332
      8.33337H51.6666C51.4999 8.33337 51.3599 8.45337 51.3399 8.61337L51.0866 10.38C50.6799 10.5467 50.3066
      10.7734 49.9599 11.0334L48.2999 10.3667C48.2599 10.3534 48.2199 10.3467 48.1799 10.3467C48.0666 10.3467
      47.9532 10.4067 47.8932 10.5134L46.5599 12.82C46.4732 12.9667 46.5132 13.1467 46.6399 13.2467L48.0466
      14.3467C48.0199 14.56 47.9999 14.78 47.9999 15C47.9999 15.22 48.0199 15.44 48.0466 15.6534L46.6399
      16.7534C46.5132 16.8534 46.4799 17.0334 46.5599 17.18L47.8932 19.4867C47.9532 19.5934 48.0666 19.6534
      48.1866 19.6534C48.2266 19.6534 48.2666 19.6467 48.2999 19.6334L49.9599 18.9667C50.3066 19.2334 50.6799
      19.4534 51.0866 19.62L51.3399 21.3867C51.3599 21.5467 51.4999 21.6667 51.6666 21.6667H54.3332C54.4999
      21.6667 54.6399 21.5467 54.6599 21.3867L54.9132 19.62C55.3199 19.4534 55.6932 19.2267 56.0399
      18.9667L57.6999 19.6334C57.7399 19.6467 57.7799 19.6534 57.8199 19.6534C57.9332 19.6534 58.0466
      19.5934 58.1066 19.4867L59.4399 17.18C59.5199 17.0334 59.4866 16.8534 59.3599 16.7534L57.9532
      15.6534ZM56.6332 14.5134C56.6599 14.72 56.6666 14.86 56.6666 15C56.6666 15.14 56.6532 15.2867 56.6332
      15.4867L56.5399 16.24L57.1332 16.7067L57.8532 17.2667L57.3866 18.0734L56.5399 17.7334L55.8466
      17.4534L55.2466 17.9067C54.9599 18.12 54.6866 18.28 54.4132 18.3934L53.7066 18.68L53.5999
      19.4334L53.4666 20.3334H52.5332L52.4066 19.4334L52.2999 18.68L51.5932 18.3934C51.3066 18.2734
      51.0399 18.12 50.7732 17.92L50.1666 17.4534L49.4599 17.74L48.6132 18.08L48.1466 17.2734L48.8666
      16.7134L49.4599 16.2467L49.3666 15.4934C49.3466 15.2867 49.3332 15.1334 49.3332 15C49.3332 14.8667
      49.3466 14.7134 49.3666 14.5134L49.4599 13.76L48.8666 13.2934L48.1466 12.7334L48.6132 11.9267L49.4599
      12.2667L50.1532 12.5467L50.7532 12.0934C51.0399 11.88 51.3132 11.72 51.5866 11.6067L52.2932
      11.32L52.3999 10.5667L52.5332 9.66671H53.4599L53.5866 10.5667L53.6932 11.32L54.3999 11.6067C54.6866
      11.7267 54.9532 11.88 55.2199 12.08L55.8266 12.5467L56.5332 12.26L57.3799 11.92L57.8466
      12.7267L57.1332 13.2934L56.5399 13.76L56.6332 14.5134ZM52.9999 12.3334C51.5266 12.3334 50.3332
      13.5267 50.3332 15C50.3332 16.4734 51.5266 17.6667 52.9999 17.6667C54.4732 17.6667 55.6666 16.4734
      55.6666 15C55.6666 13.5267 54.4732 12.3334 52.9999 12.3334ZM52.9999 16.3334C52.2666 16.3334 51.6666
      15.7334 51.6666 15C51.6666 14.2667 52.2666 13.6667 52.9999 13.6667C53.7332 13.6667 54.3332 14.2667
      54.3332 15C54.3332 15.7334 53.7332 16.3334 52.9999 16.3334Z"
      fill="#ABD18B"
    />
    <path
      class='generate-test__gear--3'
      d="M43.9065 37.3066C43.9598 36.88 43.9998 36.4533 43.9998 36C43.9998 35.5466 43.9598 35.12 43.9065
      34.6933L46.7198 32.4933C46.9731 32.2933 47.0398 31.9333 46.8798 31.64L44.2131 27.0266C44.0931 26.8133
      43.8665 26.6933 43.6265 26.6933C43.5465 26.6933 43.4665 26.7066 43.3998 26.7333L40.0798 28.0666C39.3865
      27.5333 38.6398 27.0933 37.8265 26.76L37.3198 23.2266C37.2798 22.9066 36.9998 22.6666 36.6665
      22.6666H31.3331C30.9998 22.6666 30.7198 22.9066 30.6798 23.2266L30.1731 26.76C29.3598 27.0933 28.6131
      27.5466 27.9198 28.0666L24.5998 26.7333C24.5198 26.7066 24.4398 26.6933 24.3598 26.6933C24.1331
      26.6933 23.9065 26.8133 23.7865 27.0266L21.1198 31.64C20.9465 31.9333 21.0265 32.2933 21.2798
      32.4933L24.0931 34.6933C24.0398 35.12 23.9998 35.56 23.9998 36C23.9998 36.44 24.0398 36.88 24.0931
      37.3066L21.2798 39.5066C21.0265 39.7066 20.9598 40.0666 21.1198 40.36L23.7865 44.9733C23.9065 45.1866
      24.1331 45.3066 24.3731 45.3066C24.4531 45.3066 24.5331 45.2933 24.5998 45.2666L27.9198
      43.9333C28.6131 44.4666 29.3598 44.9066 30.1731 45.24L30.6798 48.7733C30.7198 49.0933 30.9998
      49.3333 31.3331 49.3333H36.6665C36.9998 49.3333 37.2798 49.0933 37.3198 48.7733L37.8265 45.24C38.6398
      44.9066 39.3865 44.4533 40.0798 43.9333L43.3998 45.2666C43.4798 45.2933 43.5598 45.3066 43.6398
      45.3066C43.8665 45.3066 44.0931 45.1866 44.2131 44.9733L46.8798 40.36C47.0398 40.0666 46.9731 39.7066
      46.7198 39.5066L43.9065 37.3066ZM41.2665 35.0266C41.3198 35.44 41.3331 35.72 41.3331 36C41.3331
      36.28 41.3065 36.5733 41.2665 36.9733L41.0798 38.48L42.2665 39.4133L43.7065 40.5333L42.7731
      42.1466L41.0798 41.4666L39.6931 40.9066L38.4931 41.8133C37.9198 42.24 37.3731 42.56 36.8265
      42.7866L35.4131 43.36L35.1998 44.8666L34.9331 46.6666H33.0665L32.8131 44.8666L32.5998 43.36L31.1865
      42.7866C30.6131 42.5466 30.0798 42.24 29.5465 41.84L28.3331 40.9066L26.9198 41.48L25.2265
      42.16L24.2931 40.5466L25.7331 39.4266L26.9198 38.4933L26.7331 36.9866C26.6931 36.5733 26.6665
      36.2666 26.6665 36C26.6665 35.7333 26.6931 35.4266 26.7331 35.0266L26.9198 33.52L25.7331
      32.5866L24.2931 31.4666L25.2265 29.8533L26.9198 30.5333L28.3065 31.0933L29.5065 30.1866C30.0798
      29.76 30.6265 29.44 31.1731 29.2133L32.5865 28.64L32.7998 27.1333L33.0665 25.3333H34.9198L35.1731
      27.1333L35.3865 28.64L36.7998 29.2133C37.3731 29.4533 37.9065 29.76 38.4398 30.16L39.6531
      31.0933L41.0665 30.52L42.7598 29.84L43.6931 31.4533L42.2665 32.5866L41.0798 33.52L41.2665
      35.0266ZM33.9998 30.6666C31.0531 30.6666 28.6665 33.0533 28.6665 36C28.6665 38.9466 31.0531
      41.3333 33.9998 41.3333C36.9465 41.3333 39.3331 38.9466 39.3331 36C39.3331 33.0533 36.9465
      30.6666 33.9998 30.6666ZM33.9998 38.6666C32.5331 38.6666 31.3331 37.4666 31.3331 36C31.3331
      34.5333 32.5331 33.3333 33.9998 33.3333C35.4665 33.3333 36.6665 34.5333 36.6665 36C36.6665
      37.4666 35.4665 38.6666 33.9998 38.6666Z"
      fill="#57A216"
    />
  </svg>
```

Comment: крутите группу, в которой шестеренка сдвинута к центру

Comment: @StrangerintheQ на группу <g> навесил класс с анимацией, а на path     transform-origin: 50% 50%; , но не помогло

Comment: положите путь в еще одну группу, которой указан transform:translate

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо, но всё равно не заводится механизм

Comment: Проще всего формировать путь шестеренки таким образом, чтобы ось вращения совпадала с `[0,0]`. Тогда можно будет легко манипулировать, масштабировать и так далее.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```css
.rotate {
  animation: animateGears 3.5s linear infinite;
}

.ccw {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes animateGears {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="61" height="52" viewBox="0 0 61 52" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  
  <defs>
   <path 
      transform='translate(-12,-12)' 
      id=gear
      d="M19.4298 12.98C19.4698 12.66 19.4998 12.34 19.4998 12C19.4998 11.66 19.4698 11.34 19.4298 11.02L21.5398
      9.37C21.7298 9.22 21.7798 8.95 21.6598 8.73L19.6598 5.27C19.5698 5.11 19.3998 5.02 19.2198 5.02C19.1598
      5.02 19.0998 5.03 19.0498 5.05L16.5598 6.05C16.0398 5.65 15.4798 5.32 14.8698 5.07L14.4898 2.42C14.4598
      2.18 14.2498 2 13.9998 2H9.99984C9.74984 2 9.53984 2.18 9.50984 2.42L9.12984 5.07C8.51984 5.32 7.95984
      5.66 7.43984 6.05L4.94984 5.05C4.88984 5.03 4.82984 5.02 4.76984 5.02C4.59984 5.02 4.42984 5.11 4.33984
      5.27L2.33984 8.73C2.20984 8.95 2.26984 9.22 2.45984 9.37L4.56984 11.02C4.52984 11.34 4.49984 11.67
      4.49984 12C4.49984 12.33 4.52984 12.66 4.56984 12.98L2.45984 14.63C2.26984 14.78 2.21984 15.05 2.33984
      15.27L4.33984 18.73C4.42984 18.89 4.59984 18.98 4.77984 18.98C4.83984 18.98 4.89984 18.97 4.94984
      18.95L7.43984 17.95C7.95984 18.35 8.51984 18.68 9.12984 18.93L9.50984 21.58C9.53984 21.82 9.74984
      22 9.99984 22H13.9998C14.2498 22 14.4598 21.82 14.4898 21.58L14.8698 18.93C15.4798 18.68 16.0398
      18.34 16.5598 17.95L19.0498 18.95C19.1098 18.97 19.1698 18.98 19.2298 18.98C19.3998 18.98 19.5698
      18.89 19.6598 18.73L21.6598 15.27C21.7798 15.05 21.7298 14.78 21.5398 14.63L19.4298 12.98ZM17.4498
      11.27C17.4898 11.58 17.4998 11.79 17.4998 12C17.4998 12.21 17.4798 12.43 17.4498 12.73L17.3098
      13.86L18.1998 14.56L19.2798 15.4L18.5798 16.61L17.3098 16.1L16.2698 15.68L15.3698 16.36C14.9398
      16.68 14.5298 16.92 14.1198 17.09L13.0598 17.52L12.8998 18.65L12.6998 20H11.2998L11.1098 18.65L10.9498
      17.52L9.88984 17.09C9.45984 16.91 9.05984 16.68 8.65984 16.38L7.74984 15.68L6.68984 16.11L5.41984
      16.62L4.71984 15.41L5.79984 14.57L6.68984 13.87L6.54984 12.74C6.51984 12.43 6.49984 12.2 6.49984
      12C6.49984 11.8 6.51984 11.57 6.54984 11.27L6.68984 10.14L5.79984 9.44L4.71984 8.6L5.41984 7.39L6.68984
      7.9L7.72984 8.32L8.62984 7.64C9.05984 7.32 9.46984 7.08 9.87984 6.91L10.9398 6.48L11.0998 5.35L11.2998
      4H12.6898L12.8798 5.35L13.0398 6.48L14.0998 6.91C14.5298 7.09 14.9298 7.32 15.3298 7.62L16.2398
      8.32L17.2998 7.89L18.5698 7.38L19.2698 8.59L18.1998 9.44L17.3098 10.14L17.4498 11.27ZM11.9998 8C9.78984
      8 7.99984 9.79 7.99984 12C7.99984 14.21 9.78984 16 11.9998 16C14.2098 16 15.9998 14.21 15.9998 12C15.9998
      9.79 14.2098 8 11.9998 8ZM11.9998 14C10.8998 14 9.99984 13.1 9.99984 12C9.99984 10.9 10.8998 10 11.9998
      10C13.0998 10 13.9998 10.9 13.9998 12C13.9998 13.1 13.0998 14 11.9998 14Z"
      fill="#ABD18B"
    />
  </defs>
  
  <g transform='translate(10,10)'>
   <g class="rotate">
      <use href="#gear"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g transform='translate(19,31)'>
   <g class="rotate">
      <use href="#gear"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g transform='translate(25,16)'>
   <g class="rotate ccw">
      <use href="#gear"/>
    </g>
  </g>
    <g transform='translate(40,10)'>
   <g class="rotate">
      <use href="#gear"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Привет Константин Почти год не видел твоих ответов. С возвращением!

Comment: Хай, я всегда тут был, просто почему-то не отвечал)

Comment: вопросов видимо не было интересных. Хотя можешь посмотреть один, если не видел https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1330825/28748

Comment: @Alexandr_TT работы много, да и другие увлечения накатили

Answer (score 5):

Если составить путь так, чтобы ось вращения шестеренки совпадала с нулем, то любые дальнейшие манипуляции совершать гораздо проще. Обратите внимание на `viewBox="-55 -55 110 110"` - центр на x=0, y=0. Теперь можно легко масштабировать, перемещать и так далее.

```css
path {
    animation: animateClouds 3.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animateClouds {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-55 -55 110 110" height="90vh">
    <path id="cogwheel" d="M38.2 5.04c0.21,-1.65 0.36,-3.29 0.36,-5.04 0,-1.75 -0.15,-3.39 -0.36,-5.04l10.85 -8.48c0.98,-0.77 1.23,-2.16 0.62,-3.29l-10.28 -17.78c-0.47,-0.83 -1.34,-1.29 -2.27,-1.29 -0.3,0 -0.61,0.05 -0.87,0.15l-12.8 5.14c-2.67,-2.05 -5.55,-3.75 -8.69,-5.03l-1.95 -13.63c-0.15,-1.23 -1.23,-2.15 -2.52,-2.15l-20.56 0c-1.29,0 -2.36,0.92 -2.52,2.15l-1.95 13.63c-3.14,1.28 -6.02,3.03 -8.69,5.03l-12.8 -5.14c-0.31,-0.1 -0.61,-0.15 -0.92,-0.15 -0.88,0 -1.75,0.46 -2.22,1.29l-10.27 17.78c-0.67,1.13 -0.36,2.52 0.61,3.29l10.85 8.48c-0.21,1.65 -0.36,3.34 -0.36,5.04 0,1.69 0.15,3.39 0.36,5.04l-10.85 8.48c-0.97,0.77 -1.23,2.16 -0.61,3.29l10.27 17.78c0.47,0.83 1.34,1.29 2.27,1.29 0.31,0 0.61,-0.05 0.87,-0.15l12.8 -5.15c2.67,2.06 5.55,3.76 8.69,5.04l1.95 13.62c0.16,1.24 1.23,2.16 2.52,2.16l20.56 0c1.29,0 2.37,-0.92 2.52,-2.16l1.95 -13.62c3.14,-1.28 6.02,-3.03 8.69,-5.04l12.8 5.15c0.31,0.1 0.62,0.15 0.93,0.15 0.87,0 1.74,-0.46 2.21,-1.29l10.28 -17.78c0.61,-1.13 0.36,-2.52 -0.62,-3.29l-10.85 -8.48zm-10.17 -8.79c0.2,1.59 0.25,2.67 0.25,3.75 0,1.08 -0.1,2.21 -0.25,3.75l-0.72 5.81 4.57 3.6 5.55 4.32 -3.6 6.22 -6.52 -2.63 -5.35 -2.15 -4.63 3.49c-2.21,1.64 -4.31,2.88 -6.42,3.75l-5.45 2.21 -0.82 5.81 -1.03 6.94 -7.2 0 -0.97 -6.94 -0.83 -5.81 -5.44 -2.21c-2.22,-0.92 -4.27,-2.11 -6.33,-3.65l-4.68 -3.59 -5.44 2.21 -6.53 2.62 -3.6 -6.22 5.55 -4.32 4.58 -3.6 -0.72 -5.81c-0.16,-1.59 -0.26,-2.77 -0.26,-3.8 0,-1.03 0.1,-2.21 0.26,-3.75l0.72 -5.81 -4.58 -3.6 -5.55 -4.32 3.6 -6.22 6.53 2.62 5.34 2.16 4.63 -3.49c2.21,-1.65 4.32,-2.88 6.42,-3.76l5.45 -2.21 0.82 -5.8 1.03 -6.94 7.15 0 0.98 6.94 0.82 5.8 5.45 2.21c2.21,0.93 4.26,2.11 6.32,3.65l4.68 3.6 5.44 -2.21 6.53 -2.62 3.6 6.22 -5.5 4.37 -4.57 3.6 0.72 5.81zm-28.02 -16.81c-11.36,0 -20.56,9.2 -20.56,20.56 0,11.36 9.2,20.56 20.56,20.56 11.36,0 20.56,-9.2 20.56,-20.56 0,-11.36 -9.2,-20.56 -20.56,-20.56zm0 30.84c-5.65,0 -10.28,-4.63 -10.28,-10.28 0,-5.66 4.63,-10.28 10.28,-10.28 5.66,0 10.28,4.62 10.28,10.28 0,5.65 -4.62,10.28 -10.28,10.28z"></path>
</svg>
```

Условный центр не зашивается в путь искусственно, опорная точка натурально совпадает с осью вращения. Что позволяет без потерь перемещать элементы `translate` и использовать `scale` если надо.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const wheels = svg.querySelectorAll('use');

let angle = 0;
const speed = 1;
const centers = [[55,135],[127,67],[216,90]];
const directions = [1,-1, 1];
const scales = [1,1.2,0.8];

animate();

function animate(){
    wheels.forEach((w,i) => {
        w.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${centers[i][0]} ${centers[i][1]}) rotate(${directions[i]*angle},0,0) scale(${scales[i]} ${scales[i]})`);
    })
    
    angle = angle%360 + speed;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 200" height="90vh">
<defs><path id="cogwheel" d="M38.2 5.04c0.21,-1.65 0.36,-3.29 0.36,-5.04 0,-1.75 -0.15,-3.39 -0.36,-5.04l10.85 -8.48c0.98,-0.77 1.23,-2.16 0.62,-3.29l-10.28 -17.78c-0.47,-0.83 -1.34,-1.29 -2.27,-1.29 -0.3,0 -0.61,0.05 -0.87,0.15l-12.8 5.14c-2.67,-2.05 -5.55,-3.75 -8.69,-5.03l-1.95 -13.63c-0.15,-1.23 -1.23,-2.15 -2.52,-2.15l-20.56 0c-1.29,0 -2.36,0.92 -2.52,2.15l-1.95 13.63c-3.14,1.28 -6.02,3.03 -8.69,5.03l-12.8 -5.14c-0.31,-0.1 -0.61,-0.15 -0.92,-0.15 -0.88,0 -1.75,0.46 -2.22,1.29l-10.27 17.78c-0.67,1.13 -0.36,2.52 0.61,3.29l10.85 8.48c-0.21,1.65 -0.36,3.34 -0.36,5.04 0,1.69 0.15,3.39 0.36,5.04l-10.85 8.48c-0.97,0.77 -1.23,2.16 -0.61,3.29l10.27 17.78c0.47,0.83 1.34,1.29 2.27,1.29 0.31,0 0.61,-0.05 0.87,-0.15l12.8 -5.15c2.67,2.06 5.55,3.76 8.69,5.04l1.95 13.62c0.16,1.24 1.23,2.16 2.52,2.16l20.56 0c1.29,0 2.37,-0.92 2.52,-2.16l1.95 -13.62c3.14,-1.28 6.02,-3.03 8.69,-5.04l12.8 5.15c0.31,0.1 0.62,0.15 0.93,0.15 0.87,0 1.74,-0.46 2.21,-1.29l10.28 -17.78c0.61,-1.13 0.36,-2.52 -0.62,-3.29l-10.85 -8.48zm-10.17 -8.79c0.2,1.59 0.25,2.67 0.25,3.75 0,1.08 -0.1,2.21 -0.25,3.75l-0.72 5.81 4.57 3.6 5.55 4.32 -3.6 6.22 -6.52 -2.63 -5.35 -2.15 -4.63 3.49c-2.21,1.64 -4.31,2.88 -6.42,3.75l-5.45 2.21 -0.82 5.81 -1.03 6.94 -7.2 0 -0.97 -6.94 -0.83 -5.81 -5.44 -2.21c-2.22,-0.92 -4.27,-2.11 -6.33,-3.65l-4.68 -3.59 -5.44 2.21 -6.53 2.62 -3.6 -6.22 5.55 -4.32 4.58 -3.6 -0.72 -5.81c-0.16,-1.59 -0.26,-2.77 -0.26,-3.8 0,-1.03 0.1,-2.21 0.26,-3.75l0.72 -5.81 -4.58 -3.6 -5.55 -4.32 3.6 -6.22 6.53 2.62 5.34 2.16 4.63 -3.49c2.21,-1.65 4.32,-2.88 6.42,-3.76l5.45 -2.21 0.82 -5.8 1.03 -6.94 7.15 0 0.98 6.94 0.82 5.8 5.45 2.21c2.21,0.93 4.26,2.11 6.32,3.65l4.68 3.6 5.44 -2.21 6.53 -2.62 3.6 6.22 -5.5 4.37 -4.57 3.6 0.72 5.81zm-28.02 -16.81c-11.36,0 -20.56,9.2 -20.56,20.56 0,11.36 9.2,20.56 20.56,20.56 11.36,0 20.56,-9.2 20.56,-20.56 0,-11.36 -9.2,-20.56 -20.56,-20.56zm0 30.84c-5.65,0 -10.28,-4.63 -10.28,-10.28 0,-5.66 4.63,-10.28 10.28,-10.28 5.66,0 10.28,4.62 10.28,10.28 0,5.65 -4.62,10.28 -10.28,10.28z"></path></defs>
    <use href="#cogwheel"></use>
    <use href="#cogwheel"></use>
    <use href="#cogwheel"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: очень понравилось твоё комплексное решение трансформаций  для нескольких объектов. На мой взгляд это круто.  Как считал координаты центров шестеренок -centers = `[[55,135],[127,67],[216,90]];` с помощью getBBox() ?

Comment: Методом "научного тыка" и ненаучного подбора))) Можно, конечно как-то расставить их на правильном расстоянии программно, но с совпадением фазы вращения (зубчиков) пришлось бы очень повозиться, я думаю))

Comment: красиво `научно тыкаешь` :) совпадение зубьев шестеренок идеально!  Люблю шестеренки. Может видел вопрос ответ {Как при нажатии на кнопку `Stop` остановить анимацию и заморозить изображение}(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/617723/28748)